# Changing elements within a tag to something else using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following tag in an html page:

```
<li class="slogan">888-888-8888</li>
```

I am trying to change it for it to look like this:

```
<li class="phone">
<i class="icon-phone"></i>
<a href="tel:888-888-8888">888-888-8888</a>
</li>
```

I used the following code that i found to change the class name which works perfect, but i can't figure out how to change the contents to match what i want.

```
var els = [].slice.apply(document.getElementsByClassName("slogan"));
for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
    els[i].className = els[i].className.replace(/ *\bslogan\b/g, "phone");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$('li.slogan').toggleClass('slogan phone')
    .wrapInner(function() {
        return '<a href="tel:' + $(this).text() + '"></a>'
    })
    .prepend('<i class="icon-phone"></i>');
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/tqjwnt2c/)**

- http://api.jquery.com/wrapinner/
- http://api.jquery.com/prepend/

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already cycling through the tags and have the item identified els[i], all you have to do is write to the innerHTML of that item.

```
    var els = [].slice.apply(document.getElementsByClassName("slogan"));
    for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
        els[i].className = els[i].className.replace(/ *\bslogan\b/g, "phone");
        els[i].innerHTML = "NEW CONTENTS";
    }
```

Comment: awesome worked perfect, thank you very much, exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: Regexes for class values when jQuery is available?

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you [include some explanation along with it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/159034) to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's `.replaceWith()` function to do what you're after:

```js
$('li.slogan').replaceWith(function() {
  return '<li class="phone"><i class="icon-phone"></i><a href="tel:' + $(this).text() + '">' + $(this).text() + '</a></li>'
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="slogan">888-888-8888</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.slogan').each(function(){ 
   $(this).removeClass("slogan").addClass("phone"); // remove class and add .phone 
   $(this).html('<i class="icon-phone"></i><a href="tel:'+$(this).text()+'">'+$(this).text()+'</a>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="slogan">888-888-8888</li>
<li class="slogan">888-888-3626</li>
<li class="slogan">888-888-2551</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try utilizing `els[i].textContent` to set `href` , text of `a` element , `.innerHTML`

```js
var els = [].slice.apply(document.getElementsByClassName("slogan"));

for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
  var text = els[i].textContent;
  els[i].className = els[i].className.replace(/ *\bslogan\b/g, "phone");
  els[i].innerHTML = "<i class=icon-phone></i>"
                     + "<a href=tel:" + text + ">" + text + "</a>";
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="slogan">888-888-8888</li>
</ul>
```